# *** pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Empty CSV file or block: cannot infer number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

Trying the new pyarrow, this gives error:

```
data= pd.read_csv(path,sep='\t',engine="pyarrow")

*** pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Empty CSV file or block: cannot infer number of columns
```

But this works:

```
data= pd.read_csv(path,sep='\t')
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), "The “pyarrow” engine was added as an experimental engine, and some features are unsupported, or may not work correctly, with this engine."